# Using inner join to count several things

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have this query

```
SELECT playervehicles.ModelID, playervehicles.Owner, players.ID, players.Username
FROM playervehicles
INNER JOIN players ON playervehicles.Owner = players.ID
```

I am trying to order it by which model is used most as most_used and also which players own most of that model. I am very new when it comes to inner joins, and I would like a hand!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `GROUP BY`. Try this:

```
SELECT playervehicles.ModelID, playervehicles.Owner, players.ID, players.Username
FROM playervehicles
INNER JOIN players ON playervehicles.Owner = players.ID
GROUP BY playervehicles.Owner
ORDER BY COUNT(playervehicles.Owner) DESC
```

This will order them by the most used in descending order, so you get the most used at the top.